# Downloading via POP while keeping messages marked unread on server in Thunderbird

Tags: pop3, thunderbird

We have a problem with emails being marked as "read" on the server (cPanel -> WebMail) when Thunderbird downloads them via POP. Is there any way to prevent this?

**Use case and Scenario**: Several team members share and work on the same email addresses. Some use webmail and a the management uses Thunderbird to download and review and archive emails (oversight).

Team Members must be able to see emails on webmail that are not yet actually read on webmail. And yes, it is ok if the management reads the email in Thunderbird and that particular email is not marked "read" on webmail.

What's important is to only mark emails on the webmail as "Read" when someone actually read them there on the Webmail.

Comment: Sounds like a server-side problem. (POP doesn't even have the concept of "read/unread".) Does the server offer IMAP?

Comment: POP is simply download-and-delete. It only describes how to fetch new items (the CLIENT tracks what is new) and when to delete (typically straight after download). The server does not keep track of any state of a message. The fact that downloaded messages are flagged as read seems to be some exotic thing your provider does. You'll have to ask them to stop doing it or work around it (use IMAP, setup a forwarding mailbox for archiving instead of the main one,...)

Comment: I thought everytime thunderbird downloads the messages it "touches" it on server side changing it to READ state. Glad to hear this is not how PoP3 naturally works. Im an a typical webhosting provider with CPANEL, and there isn't anything "exotic" in their settings.. So i am mystified, myself. But Ill go ahead and ask them just to be sure.